# Unmarshal data in Go using stripe library

Tags: json, go, stripe-payments, marshalling, unmarshalling

Just started hacking with Go.

I'm trying to use the Stripe library. There is a type `Charge` which I am trying to use their custom `UnmarshalJSON` call, but no argument I pass seems to work. What's going on here?

```
var charge, err = sc.Charges.Get(id, nil)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

thing := charge.UnmarshalJSON([]byte(charge))
```

Here's the function: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/master/charge.go#L162

I receive:
`./hello.go:48: cannot convert charge (type *stripe.Charge) to type []byte`

Haven't found an argument to pass that will satisfy this function yet. Any help appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### JSON to `Charge`

`Charge.UnmarshalJSON()` expects a byte slice (`[]byte`). `Charge` is a struct type, you can't convert a value of it (nor a pointer to it) to `[]byte`. That's what the error message tells you.

The byte slice that is expected by the `UnmarshalJSON()` method is a JSON text describing a `Charge`, or looking into the implementation of `UnmarshalJSON()`, it also accepts a single JSON text being the `Charge` ID.

So this should work:

```
var charge, err = sc.Charges.Get(id, nil)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

err := charge.UnmarshalJSON([]byte(`"123"`))
```

Or a `Charge` struct represented in JSON (incomplete):

```
var charge, err = sc.Charges.Get(id, nil)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

s := `{"id":"123","amount":2000,"description":"testing"}`
err := charge.UnmarshalJSON([]byte(s))

fmt.Printf("%+v", thing)
```

Output should contain these fields properly set from the JSON text, amongst other fields having their zero values:

```
{Amount:2000 Desc:testing ID:123}
```

#### `Charge` to JSON

To print a nicely formatted JSON representation of a `Charge` value, use [`json.Marshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal):

```
out, err := json.Marshal(c)
if err != nil {
    panic(err) // handle error
}
fmt.Println(string(out))
```

Or use [`json.MarshalIndent()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#MarshalIndent):

```
out, err := json.MarshalIndent(c, "", "  ")
if err != nil {
    panic(err) // handle error
}
fmt.Println(string(out))
```

Example output (stripped):

```
{
  "amount": 2000,
  "description": "testing",
  "id": "123",
}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is to print this struct with nice JSON into the console. I'm coming from the JS world and I want to see a nicely printed 'object' in the console. I am printing it currently via ` log.Printf("%+v\n\n", charge)` but it kind of looks like crap. I was under the impression that I could use the UnmarshalJson to format properly/'pretty print' the struct as JSON

Comment: @AnthonyMayfield `UnmarshalJSON()` parses a JSON text. If you want to print it as JSON, you need `json.Marshal()`. See edited answer.

Comment: Whoops looks like I had it backwards. Perfect thanks a ton!